How to adjust the plot width in netlogo
In my model I must make the agents (move) in order to see runners, however, due to the energy they handle, they are moving before leaving the starting patch. I would like to know if there is a way to adjust the patches or their size, the size of the plot I am managing is 1
How change the plot size in netlogo

You can set the patch size in pixels by editing the view, but doing so won't change the behavior of your model — it will only make the view bigger or smaller on your screen.
I don't think your question is answerable as written, as it's not clear at all what you're asking — what you're actually trying to do.
